# Using refection to get all properties and pass each property in method

Tags: c#, wpf, inotifydataerrorinfo

I'm using simplemvvmtoolkit for validation (INotifyDataErrorInfo). Instead of me repeating my self over and over for each property within the view model, Id like to use reflection to get all the properties and validate them, I can't seem to figure out what to pass in the validateProperty method though.

```
    private void ValidateInput()
    {
        var unitProperties = this.GetType().GetProperties()
                                   .Where(x => x.CanRead);

        foreach (var prop in unitProperties)
            ValidateProperty(prop, prop.GetValue(this, null)); //????
                   //? ^ get errors here 


    }
```

ValidateProperty takes in:

```
    protected virtual void ValidateProperty<TResult>(Expression<Func<TViewModel, TResult>> property, object value);
```

Comment: If you've implemented INotifyDataErrorInfo, can't you just call the GetErrors(name) method for each of your property names?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is `Expression<Func<TViewModel, TResult>>` has absolutely no relation to `PropertyInfo` (the type returned by `GetProperties`). You'll also run into problems because the type of the result is not known at compile time.

The easiest solution would be to change `ValidateProperty` to accept a `PropertyInfo`:

```
protected virtual void ValidateProperty(PropertyInfo property, object value);
```

You could also convert the `PropertyInfo` to an `Expression`, but that's a bit more difficult:

```
var method = this.GetType().GetMethod("ValidateProperty");
foreach (var prop in unitProperties)
{
    var parameter = Expression.Parameter(this.GetType(), "_");
    var property = Expression.Property(parameter, prop);
    var lambda = Expression.Lambda(property, parameter);
    var genericMethod = method.MakeGenericMethod(prop.PropertyType);
    genericMethod.Invoke(this, new object[] { lambda, prop.GetValue(this, null) });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for response, changing ValidateProperty to take in PropertyInfo would require an implementation change of how the method works though right? This method is part of metadata that is part of simpleMvvmToolkit.

Comment: @TMan It would definitely require modifying the method. How drastic the changes will be depends on how it's implemented now and what other facilities are available. Most of the time, expression parameters in asp.net MVC are just used as a more syntactically pleasing (and type-safe)  way of passing a PropertyInfo into a method, so I suspect there may already be a way that do what you need with a PropertyInfo.